# Mod_Rewrite: Transform normal /url into /#!/url

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hash, server-side

I have the following two url cases …

1. http://url.com/one
2. http://url.com/category/some

If those urls are called I want mod_rewrite to call …

1. http://url.com/#!/one
2. http://url.com/#!/category/some

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
# not existing file (images, css, etc)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# no query parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
# not /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
# external redirect and pass along query string and uri as fragment
# i guess this must be an external redirect as the server side should
# not see the fragment, R=redirect, NE=dont escape #, L=last rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#!/$1 [R,NE,L]

# same but with query parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?%{QUERY_STRING}#!/$1 [R,NE,L]
```

But im not sure if this is good idea. Maybe you should do the redirect in application logic or with a client side script instead.

Comment: When I tested, it didn't show up the fragment part. I'll try it again and let you know.

Comment: Sorry the first version was more of a draft how to do it. But the current version should work (has tested it). Had to fix the flags and NE,L flags was needed to. Also you seam to need two cond/rule sets to get fancy urls when there are no query string.